# Dismissing ViewController while presenting another one

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a timer in my app. If the timer reaches 0, the user is brought to a failure page. When that happens, the previous ViewController was not dismissed, leading to more memory being taken up.

I want the previous ViewController to be dismissed if the Failure Page is presented.

```
    if (self.countdownTimer == 0) {

    FailurePage *failurePage = [[FailurePage alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:failurePage animated:YES completion:NULL];

//I want to dismiss the current ViewController when the Failure Page is presented
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
    if (self.countdownTimer == 0) {

        UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle: nil];
        FailurePage *failurePage = (FailurePage*)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"<Controller ID>"];

        [self presentViewController:failurePage animated:YES completion:^{
            [self.parentViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil]
         }];
    }
```

Comment: The app crashes once the Failure Page opens.

Comment: I use Xibs in my app though. Will this code still work?

Comment: Hi, not much familiar with Xibs, used storyboards from the start..., and suggesting you to use storyboards, easy to manage and are very useful....

Comment: I use this code except it crashes right when it is used